# pi 2 get error when run image_retraining tensorflow

Tags: python, python-2.7, tensorflow, raspberry-pi2, tensorboard

I successfully installed tensorflow to my raspberry pi 2 by followed "Installing from Pip" in this tutorial https://github.com/samjabrahams/tensorflow-on-raspberry-pi

I train the image_retraining project with object images(car, chair, table,bicycle) on may laptop and run it on pi 2. It work correctly on pi 2

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/copy $ python label_image.py car.jpg
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_def_util.cc:332] Op BatchNormWithGlobalNormalization is deprecated. It will cease to work in GraphDef version 9. Use tf.nn.batch_normalization().
car (score = 0.99672)
bicycle (score = 0.00122)
chair (score = 0.00109)
table (score = 0.00097)
```

but when I run the code I train with alphabet images on my laptop. I got errors

```
pi@raspberrypi:~/luanvan $ python label_image.py 9_9.jpg 
E tensorflow/core/common_runtime/executor.cc:334] Executor failed to create kernel. Invalid argument: NodeDef mentions attr 'Tdim' not in Op<name=ExpandDims; signature=input:T, dim:int32 -> output:T; attr=T:type>; NodeDef: ExpandDims = ExpandDims[T=DT_FLOAT, Tdim=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast, ExpandDims/dim)
     [[Node: ExpandDims = ExpandDims[T=DT_FLOAT, Tdim=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast, ExpandDims/dim)]]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "label_image.py", line 25, in <module>
    {'DecodeJpeg/contents:0': image_data})
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 710, in run
    run_metadata_ptr)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 908, in _run
    feed_dict_string, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 958, in _do_run
    target_list, options, run_metadata)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/client/session.py", line 978, in _do_call
    raise type(e)(node_def, op, message)
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.InvalidArgumentError: NodeDef mentions attr 'Tdim' not in Op<name=ExpandDims; signature=input:T, dim:int32 -> output:T; attr=T:type>; NodeDef: ExpandDims = ExpandDims[T=DT_FLOAT, Tdim=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast, ExpandDims/dim)
     [[Node: ExpandDims = ExpandDims[T=DT_FLOAT, Tdim=DT_INT32, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](Cast, ExpandDims/dim)]]
Caused by op u'ExpandDims', defined at:
  File "label_image.py", line 18, in <module>
    _ = tf.import_graph_def(graph_def, name='')
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/importer.py", line 279, in import_graph_def
    op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 2317, in create_op
    original_op=self._default_original_op, op_def=op_def)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 1239, in __init__
    self._traceback = _extract_stack()
```

I really don't understand. This command  `"python new.py 9_9.jpg"` run correctly on my laptop but get those errors when I run on Pi 2.

Would you mind helping me

thank you

Comment: The `Tdim` attribute was added recently, try using the latest version of TensorFlow.

Comment: Make sure your laptop and pi have same version of tensorflow.

Comment: seems legit. Cause I just upgrade tensorflow 0.11.0-cp27 recently on my laptop and the pi 2 version is 0.10.0-cp27.